# how to disable breadcrumb for some controllers yii2?

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I want disable or change breadcrumb in Yii2 application. How to do that.I

```
tried to change with

echo Breadcrumbs::widget([
    'itemTemplate' => "<li><i>{link}</i></li>\n", // template for all links
    'links' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Post Category',
            'url' => ['post-category/view', 'id' => 10],
            'template' => "<li><b>{link}</b></li>\n", // template for this link only
        ],
        ['label' => 'Sample Post', 'url' => ['post/edit', 'id' => 1]],
        'Edit',
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all change it back to default, which is:

```
<?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
    'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
]) ?>
```

According to [yii2 documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-breadcrumbs.html#$links-detail) if you set the value for `$links` to an empty array, breadcrumbs will not show up.

**How do you do it?**
Check above code , the `$links` value in being set by `$this->params['breadcrumbs']` variable, which is available in every `view` file. So in your view file just do this:

```
// empty if you don't want breadcrumbs
$this->params['breadcrumbs'] = [];
```

Otherwise set some value and your breadcrumbs will show up.